# Assign labels: all values are false

Tags: python, pandas

I have some problem to assign label whether a condition is satisfied. Specifically, I would like to assign False (or 0) to rows which contains at least one of these words

```
my_list=["maths", "science", "geography", "statistics"]
```

in one of these fields:

```
path | Subject | Notes
```

and look for these websites   `webs=["www.stanford.edu", "www.ucl.ac.uk", "www.sorbonne-universite.fr"]` in column `web`.

To do this I am using the following code:

```
  def part_is_in(x, values):
        output = False
        for val in values:
            if val in str(x):
                return True
                break                
        return output


  def assign_value(filename):
    my_list=["maths", "", "science", "geography", "statistics"]
  

    filename['Label'] = filename[['path','subject','notes']].apply(part_is_in, values= my_list)
    filename['Low_Subject']=filename['Subject']
    filename['Low_Notes']=filename['Notes']
    lower_cols = [col for col in filename if col not in ['Subject','Notes']]
    filename[lower_cols]= filename[lower_cols].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower(),axis=1)
    webs=["https://www.stanford.edu", "https://www.ucl.ac.uk", "http://www.sorbonne-universite.fr"]

# NEW COLUMN # this is still inside the function but I cannot add an indent within this post

filename['Label'] = pd.Series(index = filename.index, dtype='object')

for index, row in filename.iterrows():
        value = row['web']

        if any(x in str(value) for x in webs):
            filename.at[index,'Label'] = True
        else:
            filename.at[index,'Label'] = False

for index, row in filename.iterrows():
        value = row['Subject']

        if any(x in str(value) for x in my_list):
            filename.at[index,'Label'] = True
        else:
            filename.at[index,'Label'] = False

for index, row in filename.iterrows():
        value = row['Notes']

        if any(x in str(value) for x in my_list):
            filename.at[index,'Label'] = True
        else:
            filename.at[index,'Label'] = False
            
for index, row in filename.iterrows():
        value = row['path']

        if any(x in str(value) for x in my_list):
            filename.at[index,'Label'] = True
        else:
            filename.at[index,'Label'] = False
            
return(filename)
```

My dataset is

```
web                        path         Subject                Notes
www.stanford.edu        /maths/           NA                    NA
www.ucla.com           /history/        History of Egypt        NA
www.kcl.ac.uk         /datascience/     Data Science            50 students
...
```

The expected output is:

```
web                        path         Subject                Notes           Label
www.stanford.edu        /maths/           NA                    NA               1    # contains the web and maths
www.ucla.com           /history/        History of Egypt        NA               0    
www.kcl.ac.uk         /datascience/     Data Science            50 students      1    # contains the word science
...
```

Using my code, I am getting all values `False`. Are you able to spot the issue?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- The final values in `Labels` are Booleans

  - If you want `ints`, use `df.Label = df.Label.astype(int)`
- `def test_words`

  - fill all `NaN`s, which are `float` type, with `''`, which is `str` type
  - convert all words to lowercase
  - replace all `/` with `' '`
  - split on `' '` to make a list
  - combine all the lists into a single a set
  - use set methods to determine if the row contains a word in `my_list`

    - [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)

      - `{'datascience'}.intersection({'science'})` returns an empty `set`, because there is not intersection.
      - `{'data', 'science'}.intersection({'science'})` returns `{'science'}`, because there's an intersection on that word.
- `lambda x: any(x in y for y in webs)`

  - for each value in `webs`, check if `web` is in that value

    - `'www.stanford.edu' in 'https://www.stanford.edu'` is `True`
  - evaluates as `True` if `any` are `True`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data and dataframe
data = {'web': ['www.stanford.edu', 'www.ucla.com', 'www.kcl.ac.uk'],
        'path': ['/maths/', '/history/', '/datascience/'],
        'Subject': [np.nan, 'History of Egypt', 'Data Science'],
        'Notes': [np.nan, np.nan, '50 students']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# given my_list
my_list = ["maths", "science", "geography", "statistics"]
my_list = set(map(str.lower, my_list))  # convert to a set and verify words are lowercase

# given webs; all values should be lowercase
webs = ["https://www.stanford.edu", "https://www.ucl.ac.uk", "http://www.sorbonne-universite.fr"]

# function to test for word content
def test_words(v: pd.Series) -> bool:
    v = v.fillna('').str.lower().str.replace('/', ' ').str.split(' ')  # replace na, lower case , convert to list
    s_set = {st for row in v for st in row if st}  # join all the values in the lists to one set
    return True if s_set.intersection(my_list) else False  # True if there is a word intersection between sets


# test for conditions in the word columns and the web column
df['Label'] = df[['path', 'Subject', 'Notes']].apply(test_words, axis=1) | df.web.apply(lambda x: any(x in y for y in webs))

# display(df)
                web           path           Subject        Notes  Label
0  www.stanford.edu        /maths/               NaN          NaN   True
1      www.ucla.com      /history/  History of Egypt          NaN  False
2     www.kcl.ac.uk  /datascience/      Data Science  50 students   True
```

### Notes Regarding Original Code

- It's not a good idea to use `iterrows` multiple times. For a large dataset it will be very time-consuming and error prone.

  - It was easier to write a new function then interpret the different code blocks for each column.